# Application launcher icon not working Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have wanted to change the launcher icon for android and iOS in flutter I done the setting according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7sf7-S1XBU) video.

default icon is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9wNM.png) and I want to upload [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CyHs.jpg)

It is still showing the default icon.

Answer (score 0):

The package [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) only support png image format,
the one you want to use it [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CyHs.jpg) is jpg format.

Comment: Still not Working

Comment: Can you update the question with pubspec.yaml screenshot.